# PHP strtotime() using up to much memorry? "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted"

Tags: php, memory, pdo, strtotime

I've created a php script to insert rows of data into a sql database. The script was working great using hard coded string variables for the cell data but once I passed that data to the page from a form I started to have problems.

```
<?php

/******************************************************************************/
/**************************** DATABASE CONNECT ********************************/
/******************************************************************************/

$hostname = 'xxx.xx.x.x';
$database = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$username = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

try {$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);}
catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage();}

/******************************************************************************/
/***************************** MAIN FUNCTIONS *********************************/
/******************************************************************************/

function createCourses($dateArray, $title, $outline, $startTime, $endTime, $cost, $category) {

    global $DBH;
    $STH = $DBH -> prepare("INSERT INTO courses (title, outline, date, endDate, time, endTime, cost, category) VALUES (:title, :outline, :startDate, :endDate, :startTime, :endTime, :cost, :category)");

    $numDates = sizeof($dateArray['start']) - 1;
    $i = 0;

    while ($i <= $numDates) {

        $STH -> bindValue(':startDate', $dateArray['start'][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH -> bindValue(':endDate', $dateArray['end'][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $STH -> bindValue(':startTime', $startTime, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH -> bindValue(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH -> bindValue(':endTime', $endTime, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH -> bindValue(':outline', $outline, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH -> bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $STH -> bindValue(':cost', $cost, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $success = $STH->execute(); 
        $i++;

    }

    if($success){
        //true
        echo "The courses were added successfully.";
    } else {
        //false
        echo "There was an error.";
    }


}


function createDates($startDate, $endDate, $repeatType, $repeatDay, $repeatWeek, $repeatTill) {
    $dateArray = array();

    switch ($repeatType) {
        case 'none':
            //Add the initial start and end dates
            $dateArray['start'][] = $startDate;
            $dateArray['end'][] = $endDate; 

            return $dateArray;

            break;

        case 'weekly':
            //Add the initial start and end dates
            $dateArray['start'][] = $startDate;
            $dateArray['end'][] = $endDate; 

            //Find dates between startDate and repeatTill
            while($startDate <= $repeatTill) {
                $startDate  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate . "+1 week"));
                $endDate    = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate . "+1 week"));
                if($startDate <= $repeatTill) {
                    $dateArray['start'][] = $startDate;
                    $dateArray['end'][] = $endDate;
                }
            }

            return $dateArray;

            break;

        case 'monthly_date':

            //Add the initial start and end dates
            $dateArray['start'][] = $startDate;
            $dateArray['end'][] = $endDate; 

            //Find dates between startDate and repeatTill
            while($startDate <= $repeatTill) {
                $startDate  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate . "+1 month"));
                $endDate    = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($endDate . "+1 month"));
                if($startDate <= $repeatTill) {
                    $dateArray['start'][] = $startDate;
                    $dateArray['end'][] = $endDate;
                }
            }

            return $dateArray;

            break;

        case 'monthly_day':

            //Add the initial start and end dates
            $dateArray['start'][] = $startDate;
            $dateArray['end'][] = $endDate; 

            // Find dates between startDate and repeatTill
            while($startDate <= $repeatTill) {
                $currentMonth   = date('F', strtotime($startDate));
                $nextMonth      = date('F', strtotime($currentMonth." +1 Month"));
                $startDate      = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($repeatWeek." ".$repeatDay." of ".$nextMonth));
                $endDate        = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDate." +1 Day"));
                if($startDate <= $repeatTill) {
                    $dateArray['start'][] = $startDate;
                    $dateArray['end'][] = $endDate;
                }

            }

            return $dateArray;

            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }

}

$title      = @$_GET['Title'];
$outline        = @$_GET['Outline'];
$startDate      = @$_GET['StartDate'];
$endDate        = @$_GET['EndDate'];
$startTime      = @$_GET['StartTime'];
$endTime        = @$_GET['EndTime'];
$cost       = @$_GET['Cost'];
$category       = @$_GET['Category'];
$repeatType     = @$_GET['Repeat'];
$repeatTill     = @$_GET['RepeatTill'];
$repeatDay      = @$_GET['Day'];
$repeatWeek     = @$_GET['Week'];

$startDate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startDate) );
$endDate    = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($endDate) );
$startTime  = date("H:i:s", strtotime($startTime) );
$endTime    = date("H:i:s", strtotime($endTime) );

$dateArray = createDates($startDate, $endDate, $repeatType, $repeatDay, $repeatWeek, $repeatTill);


createCourses($dateArray, $title, $outline, $startTime, $endTime, $cost, $category);


?>
```

I discovered removed the following code removes the error (though the data isn't created and inserted correctly).

```
$startDate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startDate) );
$endDate    = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($endDate) );
$startTime  = date("H:i:s", strtotime($startTime) );
$endTime    = date("H:i:s", strtotime($endTime) );
```

Is using the `strtotime()` function eating up memory? I'm thinking its just an error in my code, most likely one of the loops but I can't find it.

**NOTE:**
I've read you can remove the error by adding `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` to `php.ini` remove the error but allows the script to use unlimited memory which I feel like isn't a good solution.

Comment: Depending on what values the user selects, your `while` loops in `createDates` may generate an arbitrarily large array of date strings. Then each of these is sent to MySQL as a query in `createCourses`. You don’t need to save all those strings into an array – perhaps refactor with a `createCourse` method that saves a single course, then call this when you iterate over the dates, immediately after generating them?

Comment: `strtotime()` isn't using too much memory, that's just the straw that breaks the camel's back. You need to have a look at how large your `$dateArray` is becoming while inside that loop.

Comment: @dmullings - I tried removed the `@` and got the same error. I'm passing the same strings to the page as I was using when I just hard coded the variables with strings.

Comment: @BenjiXVI - Are you saying combing the `createDates` function with the `createCourses` function? I'm not sure what you mean by "perhaps refactor with a createCourse method that saves a single course, then call this when you iterate over the dates, immediately after generating them"

Comment: @Sammitch - It's a multidimensional array with two keys and less than ten values in each key. So not very large at all.

Comment: @Craig have you actually *checked*? Because there is basically nothing else in your script that has the possibility of bloating into 128MB.

Comment: I mean write a `createCourse(...)` method that takes one single set of dates, and executes one single query. Then call that directly from inside `createDates()` for each date, instead of saving every single one of them to an array. This would be much more memory efficient, although you should also definitely check the loops that generate all the dates are behaving as you expect.

Comment: @BenjiXVI - Ahhh that makes sense. So you think passing the array and then looping through it is what's taking up so much memory?

Comment: @BenjiXVI - I edited the script with the change you suggested. Completely removed teh `datesArray` and had it enter new dates as it calculated them instead of storing them all. Everything is working great now. Thanks so much for the help!